# Removing web.config from Views folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to do away with the web.config file in the Views folders of an MVC application?

Due to a bug in the encryption feature of Web Deploy I need to just use a single web.config file in the root of the site.

see: [MSDeploy automatic encryption of connection strings, key not found in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636870/msdeploy-automatic-encryption-of-connection-strings-key-not-found-in-dictionary/21135951#21135951)

Comment: The web.config in the Views directory prevents ASP.NET \ IIS from serving up view files (among other things). I'll recommend you figure something else out.

Comment: I was hoping I could use the location node of the root web config to specifically target the views folder. Ok, no worries.

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty configuration section in the Views web.config? Also, you can decompile the msdeploy.dll code and see what it is doing for yourself.

Comment: I don't see why you can't wrap it in a location tag in the root config, it still blocks the Views folder from being served up. But, like Mike says, maybe it's better to investigate the cause of the deployment issue.